# BigQuery - streaming via java is very slow

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Im attempting to stream data from a **kafka** installation into **BigQuery** using Java based on Google [samples](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#troubleshooting). The data is JSON rows ~12K in length. I batching these into blocks of 500 (roughly 6Mb) and streaming them as:

```
InsertAllRequest.Builder builder = InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId);

for (String record : bqStreamingPacket.getRecords()) {
    Map<String, Object> mapObject = objectMapper.readValue(record.replaceAll("\\{,", "{"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

    // remove nulls
    mapObject.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);

    // create an id for each row - use to retry / avoid duplication
    builder.addRow(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()), mapObject);
}

insertAllRequest = builder.build();

...


BigQueryOptions bigQueryOptions = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().
    setCredentials(Credentials.getAppCredentials()).build();

BigQuery bigQuery = bigQueryOptions.getService();

InsertAllResponse insertAllResponse = bigQuery.insertAll(insertAllRequest);
```

Im seeing insert times of 3-5 seconds for each call. Needless to say this makes BQ streaming less than useful. From their documents I was worried about hitting per-table insert quotas (Im streaming from Kafka at ~1M rows / min) but now Id be happy to deal with that problem.

All rows insert fine. No errors.

I must be doing something very wrong with this setup. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We measure between 1200-2500 ms for each streaming request, and this was consistent over the last three years as you can see in the chart, we stream from Softlayer to Google.

[image]

Try to vary the numbers from hundreds to thousands row, or until you reach some [streaming api limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts) and measure each call.

Based on this you can deduce more information such as bandwidth problem between you and BigQuery API, latency, SSL handshake, and eventually optimize it for your environment.

You can leave also your project id/table and maybe some Google engineer will check it.

Comment: So if Im sending 6-9M batches it might take a fair bit longer? If I send more than 1K rows I will exceed the 10M limit.

Comment: We implemented our calls such as we send no more than 1k rows and no more than 10Mbyte payload limit. So it might be cases when 300 rows cover the 10Mb limit, but it might be that 1k rows don't sum up 10M. I tell you that you should experiment with the numbers and help you understand what might be slow.

Comment: You should also check the library that it should not spawn it's own thread and it should not batch your own call.

Comment: I edited the numbers as it was not correct. Our average is 2 seconds on the largest BQ project we run.

Comment: Can you include more detail in your answer about this `it should not spawn it's own thread and it should not batch your own call` statement?

Comment: I don't know your library per se, but some libraries take an input, and they are written to further parallelize that. You can quickly check this based on number of open connections. Is it clear now?